# How to update a recylerview elements inside a fragment whose data or property is changed (Room Database) from other activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

```
This is my code so far.

Fragment to which recylerview is attached.

 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mRestaurantLandingPage = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.restaurant_activity);
       // mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_dish_item_recyler_view);

        isAvailable = foodItemViewModel.getRestaurantId();
        mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_dish_recyler_view);
        mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        if (!(isAvailable == mRestaurantId)) {
            //InsertFoodIAsyncTask insertFoodIAsyncTask = new InsertFoodIAsyncTask();
            //insertFoodIAsyncTask.execute(mRestaurantId);
            insertFoodItems(mRestaurantId);
        } else {
            progressDialog.show();
            mCategory = foodItemViewModel.getFoodCategories();
            for (String category : mCategory) {
                foodItems = new ArrayList<>();
                foodItems.addAll(foodItemViewModel.getFoodByCategory(category));
                RestaurantMenuCategoryModel menuCategoryModel = new RestaurantMenuCategoryModel(category, foodItems);
                menuCategoryModels.add(menuCategoryModel);
                mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                restaurantMenuCategoryAdapter = new RestaurantMenuCategoryAdapter(getContext(), menuCategoryModels,
                        mRestaurantLandingPage, foodItemViewModel);
                mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView.setAdapter(restaurantMenuCategoryAdapter);
                restaurantMenuCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        foodItemViewModel.getAllLiveFood().observeForever(new Observer<List<FoodItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<FoodItem> foodItemList) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void insertFoodItems(final int restaurantid) {
        String mUrl = mApiUrl + "getRestaurantMenu?restaurantId=" + restaurantid;
        Log.d("Inside Database ", "from Async Hope it works");
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                mUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "response length" + response.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                       updateRoom Database

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }upDateUI();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("JSON Response", error.toString());
            }
        });
        RequestController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    private void upDateUI() {

        mCategory = foodItemViewModel.getFoodCategories();
        for (String category : mCategory) {
            foodItems = new ArrayList<>();
            foodItems.addAll(foodItemViewModel.getFoodByCategory(category));
            RestaurantMenuCategoryModel menuCategoryModel = new RestaurantMenuCategoryModel(category, foodItems);
            menuCategoryModels.add(menuCategoryModel);
            mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            restaurantMenuCategoryAdapter = new RestaurantMenuCategoryAdapter(getContext(), menuCategoryModels,
                    mRestaurantLandingPage, foodItemViewModel);
            mRestaurantMenuRecyclerView.setAdapter(restaurantMenuCategoryAdapter);
            restaurantMenuCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup
            container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RestaurantMainActivity mRestaurantMainActivity = (RestaurantMainActivity) getActivity();
        mQueryData = new ArrayList();
        mQueryData = mRestaurantMainActivity.getIntentDataForFragments();
        mRestaurantId = Integer.parseInt(mQueryData.get(0).toString());
        foodItemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FoodItemViewModel.class);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_menu_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }


Recyclerview where user can increase or decrease the food count.


holder.mAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                currentItem.setQuantityincart(1);
                currentItem.setFoodincart(1);
                foodItemViewModel.addFoodToCart(currentItem);
                holder.mAddToCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mAddButtonQuantityLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mFoodQuantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getQuantityincart()));
                showViewCart();
            }
        });

        holder.mDecreaseQuantityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                currentItem.setQuantityincart(currentItem.getQuantityincart() - 1);
                if (currentItem.getQuantityincart() < 1) {
                    holder.mAddToCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mAddButtonQuantityLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    currentItem.setFoodincart(0);
                    foodItemViewModel.decreaseFoodQuantity(currentItem);
                }
                holder.mFoodQuantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getQuantityincart()));
                foodItemViewModel.decreaseFoodQuantity(currentItem);
                showViewCart();
            }
        });

        holder.mIncreaseQuantityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Before Decrease Click Current Food Item Count " + currentItem.getQuantityincart(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentItem.setQuantityincart(currentItem.getQuantityincart() + 1);
                foodItemViewModel.increaseFoodQuantity(currentItem);
                holder.mFoodQuantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getQuantityincart()));
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Before Decrease Click Current Food Item Count " + currentItem.getQuantityincart(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showViewCart();
            }
        });


private void showViewCart() {
        mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(mRestaurantLandingPage, "Total Cost ₹ " + foodItemViewModel.getTotalPrice(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        mSnackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
        mSnackbar.setActionTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackground));
        mSnackbar.setAction("View Cart", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mCartIntent = new Intent(mContext, CartItemsActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(mCartIntent);
            }
        });
        mSnackbar.show();
    }`enter code here`




When User Clicks on snackbar user is routed to CartActivity where user can remove the item or increase or decrease the item which is passed.
```

Currently when User updates the value like increasing or decreasing or removing the food item from cart at that point in time I update the Room dB.
Next if user clicks on back button User is routed to Activity which holds the Fragment and the related recylerview but the recyler view still shows the old data like the quantity is not reset though in Db it is updated (Room DB).

I am not sure how exactly use Room DB live data and mutablelivedata in this scenario. Thanks in Advance a solution or guidance will be helpful